# lotus script to get register use OU and O?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

i am trying to get the OU and O from a user ID which is newly created

TestUser1.id

Question: i want to get full path of the new register ID.

1) **Without login** to that account to return the user ID Information ?

Full path = CN=TestUser1/OU=Software/O=pcs

```
Sub Initialize
  Dim session As New NotesSession
  Dim adminp As NotesAdministrationProcess
  Set adminp = _
  session.CreateAdministrationProcess(mailsvr)
  noteid$ = adminp.SetUserPasswordSettings( _
  "CN=TestUsesr1/OU=Software/O=pcs", PWD_CHK_LOCKOUT, 0, 0, True)
  If noteid$<> "" Then
    Dim db As New NotesDatabase(mailsvr, "admin4.nsf")
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Call ws.EditDocument(False, db.GetDocumentByID(noteid$))
  End If
End Sub
```

Actually what i really want to do is to force user to first times login an account to force user change his/her http password

i not sure this is the correct way to do it or not for a new created ID?

below link is related with this topic:

[force notes user to change password / internet password on next login using lotus script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228195/force-notes-user-to-change-password-internet-password-on-next-login-using-lotu/45278484?noredirect=1#comment77606676_45278484)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already partly answered in your linked question forcing a user to change his internet password is very easy:

- Get user document from server names.nsf
- set field HTTPPasswordForceChange to "1"

Here is some example code (no error handling, not syntax checked).
From the documentation your adminp- example should work as well, but it will lockout the user and not allow him to login if the server is configured like to check passwords...

```vb
Dim db as NotesDatabase  
Dim viwUser as NotesView
Dim docUser as NotesDocument
Set db = New NotesDatabase( yourServer, "names.nsf" )
Set viwUser = db.GetView( "($Users)" )
Set docUser = viwUser.GetDocumentByKey( "CN=TestUsesr1/OU=Software/O=pcs" )
Call docUser.ReplaceItemValue( "HTTPPasswordForceChange" , "1" )
Call docUser.Save( True, True, True )
```

Comment: thanks, i waste for so many days to find solution for register and admin process...who know just need to amend address book. Can already. Thanks a lot~